# Javascript random image rotator resize image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, html-table

New to dreamweaver (started this evening..).

I'm building a website and on every reload the idea is it generates a random image - this seems to be working perfectly however the issue is all the images are different sizes and it can look off.

Is there a way to uniform each image to the same size and alignment, I've tried adding the JS into a table within `<td>` but to no avail.

The JS I'm using is:

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

/*
Random Image Script- By JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com) 
Over 400+ free JavaScripts here!
Keep this notice intact please
*/

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()
//specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
myimages[1]="image1.jpg"
myimages[2]="image2.jpg"

var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
random_imglink()
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a static width like `width='200px'`. This will cause all images to be 200px wide by however many px tall. Note: this will not crop images.

```
document.write('<img width="200px" src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
```